# Remove XML string within a file

Tags: xml, powershell, replace

I need a PowerShell script that search in XML files for `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` and remove it.
I tried:

```
(Get-Content $file) | 
    Foreach { $_ -Replace  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>', "" } | 
    Set-Content $file;
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on [@MartinBrandl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41394268/3677139), if you need to remove multiple parts, you could do this:

```
$toRemove = '</Export>', '<Export/>', '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'

$content = Get-Content $file -Raw

foreach($part in $toRemove) {
    $content = $content.Replace($part, '')
}

$content | Set-Content $file
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work because `-replace` is **using regex** (you would have to escape your string in order to get it work). However, you can also use the `.Replace` static method for strings which *doesn't use regex*:

```
(Get-Content $file -raw).Replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>', '') | 
    Set-Content $file;
```

Note that I am using the `-raw` switch of the `Get-Content` cmdlet to load the file as a single string (instead of a string array) - so you don't need to iterate over the lines but can replace everything at once.

Comment: and for exemple to remove `(Get-Content $output -raw).Replace('</Export>', '') | 
    Set-Content $output;`
`(Get-Content $output -raw).Replace('<Export/>', '') | 
    Set-Content $output;`
`(Get-Content $output -raw).Replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>', '') | 
    Set-Content $output; ` is there a way to do it simpler?

Comment: @MartinhoVasconcelos You are changing your requirements in the comments. Please stick to your first issue as the accepted answer doesn't match your question the way this one does. If that was important you should have [edit]ed that into the question in the first place.

Comment: You can concat multiple replace together like: `(Get-Content $output -raw).Replace('</Export>', '').Replace('<Export/>', '').Replace(....) | Set-Content $output`. But since you are editing XML, it may be better to do this with XML methods (depends on your requirement).

Comment: -raw is not util here because you use ()

Comment: @Esperento57 True, its not necessary

Answer (score 1):

you can escape your string too like this

```
(Get-Content $file) | 
    Foreach { $_ -Replace  [Regex]::Escape('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'), '' } | 
        Set-Content $file;
```